# C# out of scope objects not getting collected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, garbage-collection, mstest, destructor

I'm trying to build my first unit tests and have a class that increments and decrements an instance counter in it's constructor and destructor respectively.  I have a test to make sure this works but it fails, it seems that other instances of the class from my other tests aren't having their destructor called when they go out of scope.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        ++InstanceCount;
    }

    public Customer(int customerId)
    {
        CustomerId = customerId;
        ++InstanceCount;
    }

    ~Customer()
    {
        --InstanceCount;
    }

    public static int InstanceCount { get; private set; }
}
```

```
[TestClass]
public class CustomerTest
    {
    [TestMethod]
    public void FullNameLastNameEmpty()
    {
        //--Arrange
        Customer customer = new Customer {FirstName = "John"};
        const string expected = "John";

        //--Act
        string actual = customer.FullName;

        //--Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void StaticTest()
    {
        //--Arrange
        Customer[] customers =
        {
            new Customer {FirstName = "John"},
            new Customer {FirstName = "Jane"},
            new Customer {FirstName = "Jeff"} 
        };

        //--Act

        //--Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(3, Customer.InstanceCount);
    }
}
```

I'm not passing a reference anywhere so customer should be deallocated but it is not, I've even tried calling GC.Collect() at the start of StaticTest() to force calls to the destructor but still no luck.

Could someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: The destructor would be called once the object gets collected by the GC

Answer (score 8):

C# is not C++. Destuctors, or rather finalizers, are a feature for very specific purposes, namely for handling the disposal of unmanaged resources held by your objects. **Stuffing program logic into finalizers is one of the few *very* bad ideas you can have with C#**. Why? Here's a quick rundown:

- There is no guarantee on when an object will be collected when it goes out of scope.
- Heck, there is no guarantee that a collection ever occurs if there's no memory pressure.
- There's no guarantee on the ordering in which object finalizer's run.
- There's no guarantee on when an object finalizer runs - could be right after it goes out of scope, could be a minute later.
- Heck, there is no guarantee a finalizer *ever* runs.
- There's no guarantee that, if it runs, it runs after your ctor completed. So in your case you could end up decrementing the instance count without  incrementing it. Granted, this is unlikely to actually happen, but it just might.
- Oh, it also negatively affects the performance of your entire app, but that's pretty minor compared to the evilness above.

Basically, when using finalizers, [**everything you know is wrong**](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/). Finalizers are so evil that there's a [part two](https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/) of that!

**The guideline for using finalizers is - don't**. Even if you are an experienced C# developer, the chances that you actually need a finalizer are very slim, while chances that you'll get something wrong while writing it are *huge*. If you're forced to work with unmanaged resources, follow the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/unmanaged) and use a `SafeHandle`.

If your requirement is to count instances, your best bet is using the [`IDisposable` pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose). This is a cooperative way of doing that, meaning that the calling code will have to actually `Dispose()` of your object for the count to decrement. But it *can't* be any other way. The bottom line is that in C# **there is no reliable way of doing something the moment the last reference to an object goes out of scope**.

### UPDATE:

I hope that I have discouraged you from ever writing finalizers, ever. Seriously, unless you're a pro and know for sure that you absolutely need the finalizer and can describe everything that happens on the CLR level with them, just don't. *However*. There is an ugly hack you can employ to get what you want. These two spells:

```cs
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

should force a collection to happen, which will put your objects on the finalizer queue, and wait for all of them to finish. If you run that after every test case, it should give you the behaviour you expected. But please, for the sake of us all, don't use that in serious code. I've just shown you a terribly sharp, double-edged blade. Without any handle. That's on fire. That second method isn't even guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: well ! detailed one, and +1 for that (same here too). i think today, is not my cache best day :p I had to refresh to see these responses show up.

Comment: I tried the `GC.Collect();` `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` method to see if it resolved the issue, it did but as per your advice I'll avoid it from now on and attempt a more C# design.  You've given me a lot to look through and work on.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

someone else already mentioned the difference between c++ destructor and c# finalizer so I am not going to repeat that.

In case you are wondering why your Test failed even after calling GC: Your variable never went out of scope. `customers` array holds references to all 3 `Customer` instances and the scope for `customers` array is `StaticTest` function. It will only be out of scope once `StaticTest` returns.

```
class Program
{
    static void Create()
    {
        Customer[] customers =
        {
            new Customer (),
            new Customer (),
            new Customer (),
        };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Create();
        Console.WriteLine($"Before GC Count: {Customer.InstanceCount}");

        GC.Collect(0);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine($"After GC Count: {Customer.InstanceCount}");
    }
}
```

This will give you the expected result

> Before GC Count: 3
>   After GC Count: 0

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that the reported issue was that the test failed because the customer in `FullNameLastNameEmpty` wasn't finalized, so the count was 4. But you're right, the question is unclear on what the issue actually is, so this could just as well be it.

Comment: I see this as one of the best answer, and +1 for that.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, the issue was with customer from `FullNameLastNameEmpty` but I now see that I would have had to use `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` as well as `GC.Collect()` for the functionality I was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

adding to all these answers, below are my two cents.

If its c#,

1. try add IDispoable to your class and create/override the dispose() method in your class. Then handle the decrement logic there.
2. try to use the Test Teardown/finalize method and Test initialize methods to appropriately utilize the dispose of objects after every test case is completed.

In a real world scenario, once the object's scope is done, if we want to dispose them off, calling them explicitly by implementing IDispoable would make that object a candidate for Garbage collector. if it is what your intent is.